# What can cause height() to return as a negative value?

Tags: jquery

This is my code to see the height of an element:

```
console.log($(".divText").height()); // Returns negative value
console.log($(".divText").outerHeight()); // returns zero
```

I have the code execute on a click event, the page displays the element, I am selecting the correct element and  there are no floats involved. What else can cause this to happen?

Comment: can you provide your code in codepen or jsfiddle, maybe something wrong with your css code..

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Put that code inside and also make sure min-height set to element is greater or equal than actual height;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a min-height set, height() returns the difference. So if you have min-height set to 500px and the size is 400px,

```
$('#foo').height()
```

will return -100