# height() returns a value that is lower than the actual height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following markup:

```html
<div class="accordion__feature accordion__feature--1">
  <span class="accordion__label display--1">Dashboard</span>
</div>
```

Upon inspecting `.accordion__feature--1`, it has a height of `62px`. But when running a `console.log`, it gives me the value of `-32`.

I have read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337047/what-can-cause-height-to-return-as-a-negative-value), which mentions a `min-height` being set. However, I do not have any `min-height`'s being set, so unsure what's happening?

**Demo**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $('.accordion__feature--1').height();
  console.log(height);
});
```

```css
.accordion__feature {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion__feature accordion__feature--1">
  <span class="accordion__label">Dashboard</span>
</div>
```

In the above demo, the actual height is `50px`, but it's logging out `18`. Even if it's a padding issue, that should only be a difference of 30px?

Comment: _“Even if it's a padding issue, that should only be a difference of 30px?”_ - plus 1px border on top and bottom …

Answer (score 0):

Change `height()` to `outerHeight()`

```
var height = $('.accordion__feature--1').outerHeight();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height = $('.accordion__feature--1').outerHeight();
  console.log(height);
});
```

```css
.accordion__feature {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion__feature accordion__feature--1">
  <span class="accordion__label">Dashboard</span>
</div>
```